# Google service account Delegation

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blogger, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I am working on creating a simple app in google appengine to automatically post contents on my blogspot.

I have created service account and trying to use below code for calling blogger api for posting a blog. This one fails to run with insufficient privileges error message.

```
urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(45)
service = build('blogger', 'v3')

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
            body = {
            "kind": "blogger#post",
            "id": "9999999999999999",
            "title": "SAmple title",
            "content": "SAmple blog contents"
            }
            scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger']
            credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('secret-key.json', scopes=scopes)
            http_auth     = credentials.authorize(Http())
            request = service.posts().insert(blogId="9999999999999999",body=body)
            response = request.execute(http=http_auth)
            self.response.out.write(pprint.pformat(response))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/postcontents', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

However i can access the blog details by below line

```
self.response.write(blogs.get(blogId='9999999999999999').execute(http=http_auth))
```

It seems like my service account is not associated with my blogger account(though both my google app engine and blogger uses same gmail account). how do i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Blogger doesn't support service accounts.  You will need to use Oauth2.  Authenticate your code once store the refresh token have your code then use the refresh token to get a new access token as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Initially, i tried with OAuth 2.0 token, authenticated my code and got refresh token. I was able to access blogger API. But after sometime if i access APi with same token, it is directing me to login to google account to generate new token . how do i use same token again for getting new access token ? I am planning to schedule a cron job for blog post.  Any documents or sample code would help me .

Comment: The python client library should handle getting a new access token.  Refreshtoken can expire you just need to re authorize it.   Note: this is your only option you have working code with oauth2 go with that